# GraphQL non nested relation

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to have a representation of nodes on GraphQL more akin to what jsonapi would be like http://jsonapi.org/

What I mean is if we take one of the examples on GraphQL

```
{
  hero {
    name
    # Queries can have comments!
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Have a representation that would be more along these lines

```
{
  hero {
    name
    # Queries can have comments!
    friends {
      id
    }
  },
  friends {
    id, name
  }
}
```

Is that at all possible in GraphQL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and there's nothing wrong with having a `friends` field. In GraphQL terms you can have the following part of the schema:

```
type User {
    id: ID
    name: String
    firends: [User]
}
type RootQuery {
    hero: User
    friends(forUserId: ID!): [User]
}
```

And then you can query this as you like – you can ask for friends separately:

```
{
    friends(forUserId: "12") {
        id, name
    }
}
```

But the whole idea of GraphQL is that you don't have to do multiple queries to get the information you need. If you just need a list of users – that's a reasonable query, that most people have (with arguments for pagination and so on). With that said, there's no reason to fetch a list of IDs and to send another fetch query for the data right after that.